# Object Prototype custom function [ Angular 7.2 - TS 3.2 ]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, prototype, angular7

im try to create a global prototype with a custom function.

I need this:

```
console.log({'active':1, 'profile':1}._state())
```

> {'active':true,'profile':1,'state':'root'}

I try this:

global.ts

```
declare global {
    interface Object {
        _state(): Object;
    }
}

Object.prototype._state = function (): Object {
    if (this.active === 1) {
        this.active = true;
    }

    if (this.profile === 1) {
        this.state = 'root';
    }

    return this;
};

export {};
```

When I try to use, fail with this error:

> TS2339: Property '_state()' does not exist on type {'active':1, 'profile':1}

And in my class say
component.ts

```
import '. /global.ts';

@Injectable()
export class AppState{

    constructor(){
       console.log({'active':1, 'profile':1}._state());
    }
}
```

> TS2345: Argument of type 'AppState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Object'

Answer (score 1):

So try to change the code in your file like this:

**global.ts**

```
interface Object{
  _state(): Object; 
}

Object.prototype._state = function() {
  if (this.active === 1) {
        this.active = true;
    }
    if (this.profile === 1) {
        this.state = 'root';
    }
    return this;
}
```

Then you have to insert the interface inside your typings.d.ts, so the compiler knows there is a change in Object.

**typings.d.ts**

```
interface Object{
  _state(): Object; 
}
```

In the end import your global file inside your module.

**app.module.ts**

```
// make sure the path is right
import './global.ts';
```

That should do the trick. I've tried it and the console.log works like a charm.